# CSS: height:100% vs bottom:0

Tags: css

What is the essential difference between:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
```

and

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: @maxinacube - `top` and `bottom` are valid to use together, along with `left` and `right`, for example setting them all to `0` (along with a `position:absolute`) would create an element that fills the entire browser viewport. Some older browsers, IE6 for example, did not support setting opposite sides together though.

Comment: @maxinacube: from what I can see in my Safari, Firefox and Chrome, the two sheets are equivalent. Whenever I remove either top or bottom, the layout changes. Only the combination of both being 0 gives me the effect of height:100%.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The height of the child element is determined differently for each property:

`bottom: 0` =>
child_height = parent_height - child_margin - child_border

`height: 100%`=>
child_height = parent_height

In other words `height: 100%` sets the *inner height* of the child to the same height of its parent, while `bottom: 0` sets the *outer height* of the child to the same height of its parent.

Example from https://jsfiddle.net/2N4QJ/1/

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px 
}

.parent > div {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    color: white !important;
}

#c1 {
    top: 0;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
}

#c2 {
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div id="c1">height: 100%, margin: 10px</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div id="c2">bottom: 0, margin: 10px</div>
</div>
```

More info about position/dimension:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530302(VS.85).aspx (archive link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120427121520/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530302(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: True, but then for box-sizing:border-box there is no difference. So the answer to the OP is, *essentially no difference*?

Comment: @mojuba, `box-sizing` does not apply for percentages, you can easily test this in fiddle in 30 seconds, actually I recommend you do...

Comment: @devundef `box-sizing: border-box` does apply for percentages, what it does not apply for is margins.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply that `height` set as 100% will set it to the documents height, while if you set `top` and `bottom` to 0, It will set it to align the element to the top and the bottom of the screen, it will do the same thing visually, though some older browsers may 'prefer' `height` being set to 100%.

Comment: The OP is about position:absolute, not position:fixed, which you seem to be implying.